# python plotly - left-align subplots shared category labels

Tags: python, plotly

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2,
                    shared_yaxes=True)

fig.add_box(x=[1,3,5,7], row=1, col=1, name='short')
fig.add_box(x=[3,5,7,9], row=1, col=1, name='longer')
fig.add_box(x=[1,4,6,8], row=1, col=1, name='even longer')

fig.add_box(x=[1,3,5,7], row=1, col=2, name='short')
fig.add_box(x=[3,5,7,9], row=1, col=2, name='longer')
fig.add_box(x=[1,4,6,8], row=1, col=2, name='even longer')

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
fig.update_traces(marker_color='blue', orientation='h')

fig.show()
```

[image]

But I want to align the labels left, like this:
[image]

If I understand correctly, there is no easy way to do that. I've seen people doing some hacks by adding a "right" extra y-axis, but couldn't figure it out for the subplots case. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This response has been customized for your purposes from the methods posted in the [plotly community](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-can-i-left-align-yaxis-in-horizontal-bar/36616/2). This technique frees up the y-axis position and places it on the right side. So it overlaps the graph area on the left side, making the width of the graph narrower. Furthermore, since your question is a subplot, we have narrowed the width of the graph on the right side to align the left and right graph sizes.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2,
                    shared_yaxes=True)

fig.add_box(x=[1,3,5,7], row=1, col=1, yaxis='y', name='short')
fig.add_box(x=[3,5,7,9], row=1, col=1, yaxis='y', name='longer')
fig.add_box(x=[1,4,6,8], row=1, col=1, yaxis='y', name='even longer')

fig.add_box(x=[1,3,5,7], row=1, col=2, name='short')
fig.add_box(x=[3,5,7,9], row=1, col=2, name='longer')
fig.add_box(x=[1,4,6,8], row=1, col=2, name='even longer')

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
fig.update_traces(marker_color='blue', orientation='h')

fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(domain=[0.1, 0.45]), xaxis2=dict(domain=[0.5, 0.85]),
                  yaxis=dict(anchor='free', position=0.02,
                             side='right'))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I am a bit confused about two things though: 1) why do we need to set the domains of the x-axes? and 2) why are we changing yaxis1? my understanding is that yaxis1 is the y axis of the second (right) subplot, so my expectation was that we add another "free" yaxis2.

Comment: The y-axis names for this subplot are `y(y1)` and `y2`, so the ticks is placed to the right of `y1(y)`. In this way, the scale is displayed inside the graph on the left side, so the display area of the graph has been narrowed. Once you draw the graph without specifying the domain, you will understand why.

Comment: I believe the example you referenced is indeed adding a new axis and changing the settings. y1's explanation is confusing so I corrected it to y.